# How to remove constraints suggested by debugger in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode-storyboard

I have been struggling with constraints for a few weeks now whilst learning Xamarin.iOS.

I have tried placing a `searchBar` element on a storyboard and set constraints in portrait and landscape mode. As soon as I think I got everything right I get the below warnings in the visual studio debugger:

```
2019-01-30 22:43:43.200763+0000 App4[3113:24693] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x600001378050 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf425640.height == 44   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x60000137a120 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf425640]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe7bf425460 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x6000013780f0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf525ce0.height == 34   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x6000013780a0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf525ce0.bottom == UIView:0x7fe7bf425460.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001362ad0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf425640]-(200)-[UISearchBar:0x7fe7bf421940]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001363a70 V:[UISearchBar:0x7fe7bf421940]-(200)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf525ce0]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000013787d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fe7bf425460.height == 414   (active)>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001363a70 V:[UISearchBar:0x7fe7bf421940]-(200)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe7bf525ce0]   (active)>
```

I understand that I need to remove one of these constraints as suggested by the debugger but where do I find these in Visual Studio written in code? I only have 4 constraints set in Portrait and 4 constraints set in Landscape as per below gif. If I remove one of them via storyboards there will be conflicts saying not all constraints are set properly. As you can see on the storyboard there are no conflicts showing up when I move from device to device, however when I simulate any device, flip it to landscape and flip it back to Portrait the `searchBar` element jumps up on the screen from its initial `center` position. I'm assuming this behavior is caused by the constraints I need to remove? Any suggestion will be much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to set constraints for landscape and portrait. The purpose of the constraints is to define positioning relative to the container and other elements. When device orientation changes, iOS will redraw the view and update yours constraints based on the new landscape dimensions. Try removing the constraints for landscape and see if it works.

Comment: thank you @pnavk. I have removed the 4 constraints in landscape and adjusted the ones I had in portrait to fit in landscape. However I'm still experiencing glitches when simulating on any device - I try to flip the phone, `searchBar` changes into landscape succesfully and when I flip back into portrait `searchBar` is suddenly at the top of the phone screen instead of center as it was before. Any ideas from your experience?

Comment: see the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from removing the landscape constraints, you need to make sure your constraints properly describe how you want the view to be laid out and what the size of it should be.

When I can, I avoid giving the view any explicit size constraints (height/width) and allow the sizing to be determined based on the positioning.

In order to center a search bar and make sure it is centered regardless of orientation, you only need to define the following constraints:

1. Center Horizontally in Container (where the view should be in the x-axis)
2. Center Vertically in Container (where the view should be in the y-axis)
3. Leading Space from Container (what the width of the view should be)

The first two constraints define the x and y position. The third constraint tells iOS the View should be "x" distance from the left edge of the screen. Since iOS knows that the view should be centered horizontally (1st constraint) and have x distance space from the left edge (third constraint), it can figure out how wide the view needs to be to satisfy both the constraints simultaneously.

I placed only these three constraints and produced the following result (animated gif):

[image]

Comment: Thank you again @pnavk. Although your approach did work and the simulation is behaving properly, should I be concerned about the fact that the storyboard is showing the `searchBar` view in orange tint as if I haven't declared "all" constraints? Also when swapping to `Landscape` in storyboard mode the view is way out of the center but is showing that it will be in the center at runtime with a red-dotted outline.

Comment: I use XCode Interface builder for my constraints instead of the built-in designer. When there are orange/yellow lines, thats just telling you where the view will be position based on the constraints, as long as that is in the right place you can be assured your constraints are correct. When it is red, its telling you there some ambiguity in the constraints defined and AutoLayout needs to intelligently guess where you want the view. Do you see any AutoLayout warnings in the output? If not, it's okay to move forward with the constraints defined as-is.